# Approval Process - How to get a visual on where a case is in an approval hierarchy?

Tags: approval-process, visual-workflow

Is there a way to get a "diagrammatic representation" of Visual workflow approval process (for Admin/Manager User login) as to get an insight on what step the current record is in the approval process. It is understood that these details are provided in approval history (upto current process step).
I am hoping for a flowchart with current step highlighted or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no core functions for that kind of functionality. Theoretically, there may be something on the AppExchange, but there is an alternative solution that I have used in the past.

1. Make a custom picklist field on the object that is used to store what Approval step the approval process is on.
2. Update your approval process steps so that they use field updates to set your new custom picklist field with every step's progress.
3. Use a flowchart program like Visio or draw.io to make your chart.
4. Capture multiple screenshots of the chart, each one with a graphical highlight on a different step in the flowchart.
5. Upload these images to Salesforce's Documents or Static Resources, per your preference.
6. Set up your Visual Workflow so that the value of your new custom picklist field is passed to it.
7. Make a new Formula in your Visual Workflow. Formulas in VWF can now work with text values, and should be able to handle the IMAGE function as well (this part is untested, but theoretically should work). Make your formula with CASE or a series of IFs, evaluating your custom picklist field and showing different image urls, based on what the approval step is.
8. Put this formula field in a Display Text in your Flow's screen, as needed.

If the formula doesn't work, you could get crazy and embed your Flow in a Visualforce page, which could then also directly reference your images (or a similar image formula field placed on the object in question)